# send message from service worker and listen to it in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, web-worker

I have service worker in my react app which gives alert when their is new update to the app. I am providing the part of code which is responsible for alerts. I want to logout user when their new update to app after logout. is There any way I can send message from worker file and listen to it in react app

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                "New content is available and will be used when all " +
                  "tabs for this page are closed."
              );

              alert("The new update of the app is available!");
              window.location.reload();

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log("Content is cached for offline use.");

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    });
}
```

Below is the index.js for react app where worker is regsitered.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from "./serviceWorkerRegistration";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
// import * as serviceWorker from './service-worker'
import { store, persistor } from "./Redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </>
);

serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
// serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister();
reportWebVitals();
```

I have tried to redirect to url and also to empty local storage which will remove the token and user gets logged out but both are not working.